# use foreach loop to dynamically generate HTML elements based on number of records in database

Tags: c#, html, linq

Unitime.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph2" Runat="Server">
   <div id="userPost" style="width:560px">
     <div id="firstPart">
        <div class="firstLeft">
            <asp:Image ID="imgProfile" runat="server" Height="50px"         ImageUrl="~/Images/ProfilePic/andre.jpg" Width="50px" />
        </div>
        <div class="firstRight">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnRemove" runat="server" Height="15px" Width="15px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/wrong.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="firstCenter">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <br /><asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="secondPart">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>

    <div id="thirdPart">
        <asp:Image ID="imgPost" runat="server" Height="357px" Width="476px" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div id="fourthPart">
        By:<asp:Label ID="lblSociety" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

unitime.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ActivityBoard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    WooooDataContext db = new WooooDataContext();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach(UniTime u in db.UniTimes)
            {
                lblSociety.Text = u.society;

                var time = u.timeCreated;
                lblTime.Text = time.ToString();
                lblTime.Text = timeAgo.relativeTime(u.timeCreated);

                var studentid = u.studentID;
                var un = from n in db.Students
                         where n.studentID == studentid
                         select new
                         {
                             n.username,
                             n.profilePic
                         };

                foreach (var x in un)
                {
                    string xx = x.username.ToString();
                    lblUsername.Text = xx;
                    string profile = x.profilePic.ToString();
                    imgProfile.ImageUrl = string.Concat("Images/ProfilePic/", profile);
                }


                imgPost.ImageUrl = string.Concat("Images/UniTime/", u.photoURL);
                lblDescription.Text = u.description;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am building something like a mockup of facebook. So i want to retrieve relevant data from database and insert into this HTML elements to display it. But now the problem i am facing here is that i could only display one of the records. What i want to do is to use foreach loop to loop out the users' post based on the number of records i have in my database. Is there anyway i could add HTML code into the foreach loop in the C# file to achieve the desired effect? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Look into the [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can do this. Basically you need to wrap your "userPost" div inside a repeater like "List View". "userPost" will be your itemTemplate in the listview.
Have a look at this [enter link description here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details)